# Dart GRPC Windows 10. Cannot generate code

Tags: dart, grpc

I'm following the Dart quickstart guide for grpc. I am trying to generate the Dart code on Windows 10 but I get the following error:

```
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have added the Pub\Cache\bin in my path and tried the commands from the quickstart guide in GRPC's page:

```
cd grpc-dart/example/helloworld
protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iprotos protos/helloworld.proto
```

I have also tried specifying the full path like this:

```
protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iprotos protos/helloworld.proto --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=c:\Users\[myself]\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\protoc-gen-dart.bat
```

In this case I get the following error:

```
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I have generated code successfully for C# and Go but I can't make it work for Dart.

Answer (score 1):

I'm win 10 too, And I have the same problem, I solved by this:

- First you need install the dart 2.x,then you can find this file:

```
C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\protoc-gen-dart.bat
```

- Get the plugin:

```
pub global activate protoc_plugin
```

- Then you can run this:

```
C:\workspace\tools\protoc3.6.1\bin\protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\protoc-gen-dart.bat --dart_out=./ ./xxxx.proto
```

Comment: A little more explanation about why this is needed or how it solved the problem would make this a better answer :) Or sharing a way to learn more about protoc_plugin. (I'm just reading this quickly and don't have the full context.) Thanks for contributing!

Comment: This is what I had been trying but it didn't work back then. I ditched grpc for rest. I might try again in the future.

Comment: You made it mate. Github helpers did not include that it is dart.bat, what was very helpful information when you are swiming around files you dont know. Thank you a lot ;)

Comment: So this will work: protoc --proto_path=D:\Repos\<path to protos>\ --plugin=grpc,protoc-gen-dart=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\protoc-gen-dart.bat --dart_out=./ system.proto

But the code it generates doesn't handle empty or any of the other special types, and there doesn't appear to be docs on how to create the RpcClient (abstract) that it expects.